# How to display the featured image of a page in the page itself automatically in WordPress?

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Please i need your help with the following.

The features images that i am setting for my pages are not getting displayed in the pages themselves. Is there any plugin or something i can do in order to let those featured images that i am setting for posts and pages to get displayed inside the corresponding entry?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should post this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ here

Comment: Thanks! shall i delete it form here first then post it there? What is the optimal path?

Comment: hey man i also don't know what is optimal path, bt i will surely delete this and post it on right portal . I also asked same question on meta site  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173546/what-is-the-optimal-path-i-can-use-if-question-is-posted-on-wrong-portal  , may be we got a better answer there of your question . Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
}  ?>
```

in the template where you want the featured image to display.

Comment: Oh thanks so much for mentioning that! In which file shall i append this line? in the functions.php or in some files of my WordPress theme? (+1)

Comment: Where you want it to display e.g the single.php file.

Comment: This will give you a full `<img>`, if you just need the URL use `the_post_thumbnail_url()`.